# Can any old loud noise be called stentorian?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

In his book about monsters, "The Foundling," D. M. Cornish describes the arrival of an ettin or giant: "Suddenly the whole forest seemed to burst with a stentorian cracking."

A voice can be stentorian, of course, and I could imagine a stentorian trumpet, or perhaps a heavy truck passing in a stentorian roar.

I'm not sure that pine trees snapping like matchsticks sound stentorian.

Can a loud sound of any quality be called stentorian?

For example, "A stentorian gun shot seized the rioters' attention."

Perhaps stentorian does not imply anything about the sound except that it can be heard over any accompanying din, even in the absence of a din, and perhaps that it commands attention.

"We were lolling about when our reverie was broken by a drinking glass striking the tiles with a stentorian crash."

To what extent are those accepted usages? (pun alert)

"You must have the angioplasty!" said Tom stentorianally. The Internets also like stentorially. "That tie is so loud it's stentorian."

Comment: Oxford *online* says the adjective describes the human voice, M-W only that it means, very loud. So, I guess it's your call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Stentorian](http://(Of%20a%20person%E2%80%99s%20voice)%20loud%20and%20powerful:%20a%20stentorian%20roar%20MORE%20EXAMPLE%20SENTENCES%20SYNONYMS)" is from [Stentor](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=stentor&searchmode=none), the Greek herald in the Trojan War, so the *OED* restricts the word to "uttered" sounds, but there's no reason that the word can't be used figuratively.  An apt use, however, would have the sense of making an announcement, if only of the presence of the maker of the sound.

> - (Of a person’s voice) loud and powerful:
>     *a stentorian roar*, (ODO)

Comment: It's necessarily figurative; but it's interesting you suggest the narrowest application is most apt. I see usages in the Homeric sense of "rallying". But even in the narrow sense, if Stephen Hawking turned the volume way up to make an announcement, would his voice be perceived as stentorian?

Comment: Ngram: ***stentorian sound*** : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stentorian+sound&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstentorian%20sound%3B%2Cc0

Comment: My edit removed the quotes from around "Stentor."  The quotes indicate a discussion of the word qua a word, and that's not the case here.  We're talking about the name of a fictional character.

Comment: @som-snytt The word is necessarily figurative in the sense that it metaphorically generalizes from a characteristic of one exemplar, but I meant the figurative transfer of "voice" or "tone" to things that don't literally speak.  If Hawking's artificial voice had a strong enough amplifier it could be literally stentorian by definition.  When Hawking "speaks" on physics, scientists hear a stentorian voice no matter how few decibels it has.

Comment: Ngrarm stentorian sound,stentorian voice.  "Sound" doesn't even register on the graph. :https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stentorian+sound%2Cstentorian+voice&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstentorian%20sound%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstentorian%20voice%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cstentorian%20sound%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cstentorian%20voice%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It does, at a very low level of usage though.

Comment: @Josh61 Your eyes must be better than mine.  I'm not saying that Ngram fails to find "stentorian sound."

Comment: I am just showing that *stentorian* is used, though rarely, referring to a noise/sound which is not a voice.   'Then the wind spat the rain on my pane The cat's paw reached out in hungry pain Stentorian sound of the clock's alarm Brought me back to my duties plain.'

Comment: @Josh61 Thx for additional points. It suggests to me: for non-voice, must be ironic or acutely aware of extending it; and I also agree that a voice can be stentorian w/o meaning "full, rich voice" (Patrick Stewart), thinking of stentorian women's voices.

Comment: ngram viewer is hilarious. "To answer the frenetic tone of a young person with the stentorian tone of officious and sedentary life" suggests "authoritative" rather than loud. Google lists the unfortunate revision: "settled and regulated officious life". Also interesting that it may be a compliment or complaint applied to musicians, vocalists or instrumentalists, probably to mean commanding vs plain loud.